# Multiple alternate row colors

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have 14 hex colors I want to alternate as background color.

How would I do that? And I also want to avoid getting the same color twice in a row.

Let's say I have the colours: blue, red, yellow, black, pink, white

I wouldn't want yellow, black, black, black, blue, white, white.....

Could someone show me in the right direction.

```
<?php 
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM custom WHERE id = $id") as $row):
?>
<tr bgcolor="#C6A511">
<td colspan="25"><?=$row['a']?></td>
<td colspan="8"><div style="width:50px; background:ONE-OF-THE-14-BACKGROUND-COLORS-HERE">&nbsp;</div>    </td>
<td colspan="8"><?=$row['c']?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: put the row colors in an array, introduce a counter, and use the counter index with a mod to retrive the background color from the array. and increment count

Answer (score 1):

For a pure CSS route you might like to look at the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo-class.

A good overview on how the selector and associated equations work on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$rownum = 0;
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM custom WHERE id = $id") as $row):
?>
<tr bgcolor="#C6A511">
<td colspan="25"><?=$row['a']?></td>
<td colspan="8"><div style="width:50px" class="bg<?php echo ($rownum++) % 14; ?>">&nbsp;</div>    </td>
<td colspan="8"><?=$row['c']?></td>
</tr>
```

Don't forget to create the `bg0..13` classes in CSS.